# How to loop through a map list to obtain values and add to IAM policy terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have a map list object and I want to be able to interate through each iam group to be able to obtain the iam user arn and add that as part of my iam policy. So far I have the following :

**Variables.tf**

```
variable "iam_user_groups" {
  type        = map(list(string))
  description = "iam user groups which consist of iam users"
}
```

**tfvars**

```
iam_user_groups = {
  all-users = [
    "list of arn will be placed here",
    "list of arn will be placed here",
    "list of arn will be placed here",
  ],

  finance-users = [
    "list of arn will be placed here",
    "list of arn will be placed here",
    "list of arn will be placed here",
  ]
```

Ideally I want to be able loop through a certain iam group for example all users and have this placed in my iam policy within the following section :

```
principals {
  type = "AWS"
  identifiers = [
    "I want to get all finance-users as part of the iam_user_groups variable",
  ]
}
```

So far I had the following but this is just getting the name of the group which I cannot use :

```
principals {
  type = "AWS"
  identifiers = [
    "aws_iam_group.iam_group_team['finance-users'].arn",
  ]
}
```

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "iam_group_team" {
  for_each = var.iam_user_groups
  name     = "${local.csi}-${each.key}"
  path     = "/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since that is already a list of users, you can reference the varaible value:

```
principals {
   type = "AWS"
   identifiers = var.iam_user_groups["finance-users"]
 }
```